# Acessar valor em resposta HTTP

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Olá!!

Estou implementando um método de login. Quando o usuário efetua o login, o backend gera um JWT e envia o token para ser armazenado no localStorage do HTML. 
Nunca utiligei TS/Angular 4, no AngularJS não tinha problema com isso, vejam minha função, sabem me dizer o prq de não estar funcionando? O `console.log("response: ", response.body.token)` está retornando null.

```
login() {
  this.auth.authenticate(this.creds)
    .subscribe(response => {
        console.log("response: ", response.body.token)
        this.auth.successfulLogin(response.headers.get('Authorization'))
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('DetalhesViagemPage')
      },
      error => {})
}
```

Retorno de `console.log("response: ", response.body)`:

```
response:  {"nome":"Frederico","_id":"5b21a4332a5e3333cc64a12f","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyIkX18iOnsic3RyaWN0TW9kZSI6dHJ1ZSwic2VsZWN0"}
```

Comment: já tentou `response.headers('Authorization')`?

Comment: Desculpa, mas não entendi o que não está funcionando.Seria o salvar no localStorage?
Se o que você precisa é retornar o token passa o que está no body.
 this.auth.successfulLogin(response.body.token);

Comment: @RicardoPontual Como eu posso passar o token através do header, utilizando express/node?
`response.headers.get('Authorization')` retorna null, creio que prq estou recebendo o token pelo body.

Comment: @LucasBrogni
O `console.log("response: ", response.body.token)` está retornando null. Porém, como podem ver, no retorno de response.body existe a key token :/

Comment: e o restando do header vem preenchido? se inspecionar `response.headers` tem algo?
para setar o token no `nodejs` é simples assim:  `response.set('token', 'valor')`. Uma dúvida, é uma requisição no mesmo domínio ou *cross-domain* ?

Comment: Se você estiver fazendo uma requisição para um domínio diferente precisa informar que esse header pode ser exposto (o token), assim: `response.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'token')`

Comment: @RicardoPontual o backend é localhost, mesmo domínio :/ Estou utilizando CORS também, está liberada cross-domain. Acho que ontem havia testado com response.set, vou tentar novamente aqui.

Comment: isso, posta ai o resultado se deu certo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78948/discussion-between-fred-and-ricardo-pontual).